# How to make component positioning in mig layout

Tags: java, miglayout

bad part in the red square:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBjtp.png]

the question is how can i make every panel to be the same size only B3 and B4
need to be half of the other panels. Can someone help me? if I set the size

This happens if i force the pane sizes i will have this gap next to B4:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CpGn.png]

```
for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++) { //this is the for cycle

 if (i == 0){
            panel.add(pane,"wrap,cell 0 0 14 0,right"); // creating the first //panel the time panel in the right corner

        }
        if (i == 58){
            panel.add(pane,"cell 0 9 1 0,left");
        }
        if (i == 59){
            panel.add(pane,"cell 1 9 14 1,left,span");
        }

        if (i>0 & i<3){
            panel.add(pane, " push,grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span,push, grow");
        }
        if (i==3){
            panel.add(pane, " push,grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span ,push, grow");
        }
        if (i>3 & i<7){
            panel.add(pane, " push,grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span,push, grow");
        }
        if (i==7){
            panel.add(pane,"wrap 3, push, grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span ,push, grow");

        }

        if (i>7 & i<10){
            panel.add(pane, "push , grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span,push, grow");
        }  
                    if (i==10){
                        panel.add(pane, "push , grow,split 2, w 0, h 0, , "  ); // split it to two this is what dosn't works
                        pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                        pane.add(button, "span,push, grow");
                    }
                    if (i==11){
                        panel.add(pane, "push ,grow,");
                        pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                        pane.add(button, "span,push, grow");
                    }
        if (i>11 & i<15){
            panel.add(pane, "push , grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span,push, grow");
        } 
        if (i==15){
            panel.add(pane,"wrap 3, push, grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span,push, grow");
        }
        if (i>15 & i<22){
            panel.add(pane, "push , grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span ,push, grow");
        }
        if (i==22){
            panel.add(pane,"wrap 3, push, grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span ,push, grow");
        }
        if (i>22 & i<29){
            panel.add(pane, "push , grow");
            pane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            pane.add(button, "span ,wrap 3,push, grow");
        }
```

where i=10 and i=11 that is the B3 B4 panel I try to with the split fuction but dos not work.

Answer (score 0):

**split [count]**
splits the cell in a number of sub-cells. Practically this means that *the next count number components* will be put in the same cell, next to each other without gaps. Only the first component in a cell can set the split, any subsequent split keywords in the cell will be ignored.  *"split"*, *"wrap" or "newline"* will break out of the split cell. The latter two will move to a new row/column as usual.

So remove additional parameters, which break proper split function.

It is equally easy and intuitive to split cells.

```
panel.add(comp1);
panel.add(comp2, "split 2"); // Split the cell in two
panel.add(comp3); // Will be in same cell as previous
panel.add(comp4, "wrap"); // Wrap to next row
panel.add(comp5);
```

Visually its looks like that:

[image]